# How can I set opacity for an image in GIMP 2.6.x?

Tags: gimp, transparency

I've searched and found advice to use a GIMP layers dialogue in e.g. [How do you get transparent colour on Gimp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8898/how-do-you-get-transparent-colour-on-gimp/9071#9071) However, in my version of GIMP (2.6.8 for Mac), Layers doesn't seem to be set up to display a dialogue. I've seen it in previous versions but hunted and not found anything under the Layers menu that will bring up the Layers dialogue.

How, in the present version of GIMP, can I set the opacity image-wide to 30% or 70%?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using 2.8 for a while but most things are still similar to 2.6 --

The layers dialog can be shown from Windows->Dockable Dialogs->Layers.

The other option is the little popup menu to the right of every dialog (little square with a triangle in it). Click it and select Add Tab->Layers. Once a tab is added you can drag it out to a new dialog.